# My table view doesn't populate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using this tutorial on how to create a pop out menu.
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

I got it working when going through the tutorial, now i'm trying to implement it into my app.

I'm at the stage where i can press the menu button and the popout menu appears. The problem is, it doesn't populate itself with my table view cells.

I set the identifiers for each table view cell and then in the code reference them to full an array.

I know when woking through the tutorial, if I misspelled one of the identifiers when defining what's in the array, the program would crash. In my app, that's not the case. Hopefully that can help pin down the problem. It doesn't even change the colours which is the first part of the code.

Here's the code.

```
#import "SidebarViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"


@interface SidebarViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;


@end

@implementation SidebarViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15f alpha:0.2f];

_menuItems = @[@"markup",@"tax"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.menuItems count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: SInce the first piece of code that is supposed to execute should change the colour so it's very dark (which worked in my tutorial file), i assume something is wrong with the connection between the code and the object. I have checked the connections inspector and my current project has the exact same connections as my tutorial file.

Comment: Might sound like a stupid question but did you check the class of your table view controller object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I feel like such a noob. It turns out the ViewControler didn't have a target, hence why it wasn't responding.

I'm so sorry for wasting your time, I really feel bad now.

Answer (score 2):

All you're doing is creating an array with two string literals. You must set the textlabel's `text` property in the following method to display the strings in table view cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [_menuItems objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to add 'tableView.delegate = self;` and `tableView.dataSource = self;` and implement the two correctly.

Comment: I've checked, delegate and data sources are set to self. Sorry Kraken, that code didn't do anything, still appearing blank.